# How to build a JPA 2.0 query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two entities: Event and Comment.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long eventId;

    @Column(name = "title", length = 200)
    protected String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    protected List<Comment> comments;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "comment_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long commentId;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", referencedColumnName="event_id", nullable = false)
    protected Event event;

    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date updatedTimestamp;
}
```

So each event has a list of comments and each comment has an update time.

I want to use Criteria API to construct a query such that choose all events that has at least one new comments. (New comment means its update time is later than a given date time)

Thanks for anyone helping me.

---

Sorry the question I asked above is not complete: what I want is use Criteria API to construct a query such that choose all events that has at least one new comments **and eventId is equal to some specific eventId**.

I have tried: (Given `Date lastCheckedTime` and `Long eventId`)

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Event> cq = cb.createQuery(Event.class);
Root<Comment> c = cq.from(Comment.class);
Predicate lastCheckedTimeCondition = cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
     c.get(Comment_.updatedTimestamp), lastCheckedTime);
cq.where(lastCheckedTimeCondition);
cq.select(c.get(Comment_.event));
TypedQuery<Event> query = em.createQuery(cq);
result = query.getResultList();
```

the above code can choose events that have new comments but now I don't know how to add the conditon about the eventId.

Comment: This is not a good fit for the q/a format here I think. You shouldn't just post an assignment and ask people to do it. Better is to try something and when you get stuck ask for specific help.

Comment: JPQL is much easier to use for such a static query. Why don't you use JPQL? Moreover, once you have the JPQL query, translating it into criteria will be easier.

Comment: @ArjanTijms ok, I will post what I have tried so far.

Comment: @Thomas I have posted what I have tried so far.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your advice, but in order to be consistent with previous code, I need to use Criteria API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a join on the event, and apply the restriction on the ID of the event:

```
Join<Comment, Event> event = c.join(Comment_.event);
Predicate eventIdPredicate = cb.eq(event.get(Event_.eventId), theEventId);
```

And then use CriteriaBuilder's and method to combine the two predicates into one as shown by Lukas's answer.

Comment: Ah, crazy, I've missed the need for a join in this case. JPA's verboseness always gets me...

Comment: Hi, when I use the code above to retrieve events, I can't get the associated comments. There is an exception: com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method. Do you know why this occurs?

Comment: No. Having the stack trace would help.

Comment: It doesn't have a stack trace. I can get the list of events, but the comments associated become Persistence bag.

Comment: Sorry it is ok now, it is the error in other place and I have fixed that.

Comment: And one more question: can I use Path<Event> event = c.get(Comment_.event) instead of Join?

Comment: I think so, yes. Try it and you'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

`CriteriaBuilder` has an [and(Predicate...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#and%28javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...%29) method. You would then connect your two predicates:

```
cq.where(cb.and(lastCheckedTimeCondition, someEventIdCondition));
```